# Quickblox Android: How to know chat room is members-only or open?

Tags: android, chat, quickblox, chatroom

I am not found any way to know the room is open or members-only.

Problem is that its show all the room in list whether its open or members-only. i want to show the room list only open and members-only(if user is in the list).

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Currently this functionality is under development. Next week we are going to make an update where it will be included.

Comment: SDK has been updated http://quickblox.com/developers/Android#Framework_changelog

Comment: You can also check this doc http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Retrieve_room_info